# A reference to infinite version of the Sunflower Lemma

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, set-theory

Please help me to find a proper reference to the following infinite version of the Sunflower Lemma.

> **Lemma.** Let $n\in\mathbb N$. Every infinite family of $n$-element sets contains an infinite subfamily $\mathcal F$ such that $A\cap B=\bigcap\mathcal F$ for any distinct sets $A,B\in\mathcal F$.

Browsing through Internet I could find only finite and uncountable versions of the Sunflower Lemma (but not the countable one).

Comment: The uncountable version is usually known (as I'm sure you know, but didn't mention) as the $\Delta$-system lemma.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins You are right. But the finite Sunflower lemma also often is referred as $\Delta$-lemma, see http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=The_Erdos-Rado_sunflower_lemma

Comment: Indeed, I like the sunflower terminology, which is attractively evocative of the essence of the situation. Is there a common usage of the sunflower terminology in the uncountable case? I've not heard of this terminology until now. I find the sunflower metaphor a little more accurate than the $\Delta$-metaphor.

Comment: I think now that actually I have heard of the sunflower terminology before, although it is much less commonly used in set theory than the $\Delta$-system terminology. Still, I think I prefer the sunflower imagery.

Comment: I had seen the "sunflower" terminology once before. I think it was in a computer science paper.  The sunflower picture nicely matches my mental picture of the basic situation. Often, though, I need (or at least want) the improved version that says the root (or kernel or...) is an initial segment of each of the sets in the $\Delta$-system; then the sunflower looks rather lopsided.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that that is a common extra asymmetric component of the $\Delta$-system situation. But I suppose it follows anyways that any sunflower can be refined to such a kind of sunflower.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Not at all -- that version of the lemma simply describes freshly opened sunflowers http://photos.capturememphis.com/photos/1BD_TvOSPqkevXxpdVS3tg/display.jpg.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found it in the book Komjáth, Péter; Totik, Vilmos, [**Problems and theorems in classical set theory**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/0-387-36219-3), Problem Books in Mathematics. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 0-387-30293-X/hbk). xii, 514 p. (2006). [ZBL1103.03041](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1103.03041). It's stated on p. 107 as the first item in the chapter on $\Delta$-systems:

> 1. An infinite family of $n$-element sets ($n\lt\omega$) includes an infinite $\Delta$-subfamily.

A proof is given on p. 421. No reference is given.